# Insert a number in table without special character

Tags: plsql

I need a procedure or function for validation-
if i insert data in a column then only that numbers will enter which have only integers not special character not alphanumeric values.

Comment: You can just create the column as NUMBER and Oracle will do the rest.

Comment: Please rewrite your question, add an input and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you need a function that in a string with numbers, letters and special characters will keep only the numbers.

In that case try with [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_replace.php)

E.g.:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('1/A2!46', '([^0-9])+', '') FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('1/A2!46','([^0-9])+','')
-----------------------------------------
1246
```